# Passport error when serialize with another strategy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Create a new type of login for a different type of user (another list in the database), the login succeeds but it doesn't serialize me grow and then show it (just like it does for user). Any idea what it could be ?
Passport Config:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../model/User')();
var Grow = require('../model/Grow')();

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
    // Match Email User
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'No se encontro el usuario' });
    } else {
        // Match Password User
        const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
        if (match) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Contraseña incorrecta' });
        }
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('growlocal', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
    const grow = await Grow.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!grow) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'No se encontro el usuario' });
    } else {
        const match = await grow.matchPassword(password);
        if (match) {
            return done(null, grow);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Contraseña incorrecta' });
        }
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser((grow, done) => {
    console.log(grow)
    done(null, grow.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log(grow)
    Grow.findById(id, (err, grow) => {
        done(err, grow);
    });
});
```

Router Config:

```
// Login Grow
router.get('/grows/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('growlogin');
});


router.post('/grows/signin', passport.authenticate('growlocal', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/grows/signin',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

EJS:

```
 <% if (grow){ %>
        <a href="">Gato</a>
        <%}%>
```

Error: 
[image]

If anyone has any idea how to fix it, please let me know. It is very important for the development of my application. Thank you very much <3

Comment: I already solved the ejs error adding this to global variables in app.js (res.locals.grow = req.grow || null;) but the login doesnt send any value for grow!

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.